# How to write a .htaccess to access multiple CodeIgniter projects in different environments?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've two CodeIgniter v2.1.4 projects running in 2 separate subdirectories, namely **dev** and **prod**.  Below is the file structure:

```
/ (root)
.htaccess (01)
  - dev
      - .htaccess (02)
      - application
      - system
      - assets
          - js
          - css
          - img
  - prod
      - .htaccess (03)
      - applications
      - system
      - assets
          - js
          - css
          - img
```

What I want to do is

- if user goes to **www.abc.com**, users are redireced to **www.abc.com/prod**, hiding **prod** in URL.
- if user goes to **www.abc.com/prod**, users are redirected to **www.abc.com/prod**, **prod** is displayed in URL.
- if user goes to **www.abc.com/dev**, users are redirected to **www.abc.com/dev**, not necessary to hide **dev** in URL.

Below is my ***.htaccess (01)***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /prod
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prod/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

***.htaccess (02)***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|changelog\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

***.htaccess (03)***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|changelog\.html)
RewriteRule ^prod/(.*)$ /prod/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

ISSUE: What doesn't work now is files in **assets** folders must have **dev** or **prod** in URL to load, e.g.

- www.abc.com/prod/assets/js/jquery.js ✔ it works!

  www.abc.com/assets/js/jquery.js **×** fail...

Answer (score 0):

Below should be your .htaccess (01)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ /prod/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule !^prod/ /prod/index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

You can leave rest of your code as is.